# Combobox textChanged event not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

We have customar table contains Cust_ID, Cust_Name etc..... 
for this table Cust_Name is not unique and one Customer name can repeat Number of times.

i am getting data from SQL and binding to ComboBox (winform)

```
 cmbCustomar.Datasource = GetCustomerData(_LocationID);
 cmbCustomar.DisplayMember = "Cust_Name";
 cmbCustomar.ValueMember = "Cust_ID";
```

Here the Problem is :

**Customer Name : JOHN is repeated 4 times, all Cust_ID are different
when user select JOHN on first Item i am getting correct "SelectedValue"**

but if user select 2 nd or 3rd JOHN 
Combobox Item it allways default select First Item (Name as JOHN) 
and the SelectedValue allways return the First Item Value.

i am not able to find where i am doing wrong, please suggest.

Comment: If you post the code how you are accessing the selected value,then we can understand.Are you sure? you are using "SelectedValue" and casting it properly.

Comment: Keep in mind "SelectedValueChanged" event will fire when combobox being populated. Make sure you subscribe to this event after the combobox has been populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the following property:

```
cmbCustomar.DropDownStyle = DropDownList;
```

If your ComboBox has `DropDownStyle = DropDown`, then the "text" part of the ComboBox is trying to match the first item it can find in the list, and in this case, it ignores the current selected item and finds the first "John" on your list.

Comment: thank you LarsTech, this property change fixed my combobox issue.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind "SelectedValueChanged" event will fire when combobox being populated. Make sure to un-subscribe to this event before populating the combobox. and subscribe again after populating the data.

```
            //unsubsribe the event before populating combobox1
        this.cmbCustomar.SelectedValueChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.cmbCustomar_SelectedValueChanged);

        cmbCustomar.Datasource = GetCustomerData(_LocationID);
        cmbCustomar.DisplayMember = "Cust_Name";
        cmbCustomar.ValueMember = "Cust_ID";

        //subscribe the event again 
        this.cmbCustomar.SelectedValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbCustomar_SelectedValueChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are very new to it. And as by my guess, because of your incomplete description, you are trying return the "Selected Value" based on the selected text of the combobox. But rather than that you must try to attach a value a to selected text and return that value. It will surely solve your problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No.  The problem is reproducible.  Try it.

Comment: what is reproducible....please clarify. as i am understanding the question my solution should work

Comment: Drop a ComboBox on a form, create a simple Customer class with CustID and CustName properties, create a List<Customer>, add (1, "John"), (2, "John"), (3, "John"), set the ComboBox.DataSource to the list, DisplayMember to CustName, ValueMember to CustID.  Select the 3rd John on the list, then drop the list again-- the 1st John is selected, not the 3rd.  Note, however, that SelectedIndexChanged didn't fire.  It's really just a display problem.

Comment: @LarsTech I am unable to reproduce this in VS 2010 .net 4.0 .In my test project SelectedIndexChanged  is firing correctly.